# Laravel Passport Client authentication failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

There's a problem with the Laravel Passport.

```
User::create($request->all())->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken
```

User is created ok, model returned. but crashes with error Client authentication failed

I've analyzed Passport's source code and understood that passport class **ClientRepository** property *$record->grant_types* returns null, so throw exception. Did someone has faced with this? How to solve it?